# Does concentrated HNO3 oxidize aluminium to form a protective oxide layer, or is the oxide layer already present so HNO3 is unable to react?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, solutions, concentration, theoretical-chemistry

Sources on the internet like this [one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/215904038_Reaction_of_aluminium_with_diluted_nitric_acid_containing_dissolved_sodium_chloride_On_the_nature_of_the_gaseous_products) only say that aluminium does not react with concentrated or dilute $\ce{HNO3}$.

I have seen other related questions on this site but none answers my question specifically. I have read that aluminium on contact with air forms a protective oxide layer, so this layer should protect it from conc $\ce{HNO3}$.

Does conc $\ce{HNO3}$ "further oxidize" aluminium to aluminium oxide?

Comment: Please use proper punctuation in the future.

Comment: Standard aluminum etch is on the order of 25:5:1 phosphoric-acetic-nitric, with additional nitric increasing the etch rate.

Comment: @SafdarFaisal This is definitely a duplicate, but it's a shame that the answer to the post you link to doesn't cite more authoritative references.

Answer (score 0):

The aluminum oxide layer ($\ce{Al2O3}$) produced by air oxidation on metallic aluminium protects the metal against further oxidation by both air and nitric acid.